# Prove that Log Det is concave

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'm trying to **prove the log-concavity of the determinant in $S^n_{++}$**

Proving this is equivalent to proving that :
$\forall X,Y \in S^n_{++}, \forall \theta \in [0,1], Det(XY^{-1})^{-\theta}(\theta Det(XY^{-1}) + 1 - \theta) \geq 1$, correct?

I'm stuck here. I could only manage to prove that it was greater than 0.

Could anyone give me a hint, please?

Comment: What is the notation $S^n_{++}$?

Comment: It's the set of Symmetrical, positive, definite matrices @ConnorHarris

Comment: Please provide more context for this question, especially where you got the possibly equivalent statement and what you've tried so far.

Comment: I started with the following expression of a log-concave function f:
$ f(\theta x + (1 - \theta)y) \geq f(x)^\theta f(y)^{1-\theta}$

By replacing f() with Det(), we get:
$\theta Det(X) + (1 - \theta) Det(Y) \geq Det(X)^\theta Det(Y)^{1-\theta}$

I then divided the left side by the right side, which led me to the inequality in my question.

Hope that helps! @BrianBorchers

Comment: Why does $\det(\theta X+(1-\theta)Y)=\theta\det(X)+(1-\theta)\det(Y)$?

Comment: Oh I mistook Det for a linear map. My bad. 

Do you see any way of proving the inequality, though? @user10354138

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

For $A$ is $n\times n$ positive definite real matrix  we have

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-\langle Ax, x\rangle} d x =\frac{\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}} {\sqrt{\det A}} $$

Apply  [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) to
$f(x) = e^{-\langle Ax, x\rangle}$ and $g(x) = e^{-\langle B x, x \rangle}$

Comment: I don't think 2 should be there.

Comment: @user10354138: You are right, thank you for correcting!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: To prove $\det(\theta X+(1-\theta)Y)\geq(\det X)^\theta(\det Y)^{1-\theta}$ for all $X,Y\in S_{++}$, $\theta\in(0,1)$, reduce to the case $X,Y$ commute and the result follows from weighted AM-GM after simultaneous diagonalisation.

Comment: Thanks! Could you just clarify what you mean by "reduce to the case X,Y commute"?

Comment: Use the property $\det(A)\det(B)=\det(AB)$ of determinant and $X,Y\in S_{++}$ to reason why it suffices to prove the case $XY=YX$ where you can simultaneously diagonalise $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Thank you!

I'm not sure I did exactly what you expected, but here's where I am currently:

$Det(\theta X + (1- \theta) Y) = Det(\theta X Y^{-1} + (1-\theta) I_n )$
And since $XY^{-1} \in S_{++}$, we can diagonalise it :
$= Det(\theta Q D Q^T + (1-\theta) Q Q^T) = Det(Q(\theta D + (1-\theta) I_n)Q^T) = Det(QQ^T) \prod_{i=1}^{n} {\theta \lambda _i + 1 - \theta)}$

Where Q is an orthogonal matrix, and $QQ^T = I_n$

Where can I can go from here? @user10354138

Comment: @frenchstudent00 No, you fell into the trap of thinking $S_{++}$ is closed under multiplication.  There is no reason why product of symmetric matrices are symmetric, e.g. $\begin{pmatrix}1\\&a&b\\&b&a\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\b&a\\&&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\ab&a^2&b\\b^2&ab&a\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: But I'm referring to symmetric, definite, positive matrices. And my textbook said to assume that $XY^{-1}$ too, was symmetric definite positive @user10354138

Comment: You can make the two matrices positive-definite by making $a\gg b>0$.  Indeed the product of symmetric positive-definite matrices have all eigenvalues positive, and in fact is similar to a symmetric positive-definite matrix.  That is part of the proof I tried to steer you to come up with but apparently I failed.

Comment: @frenchstudent00 After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).